# Java SQL exception command not properly ended

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

help me with the below issue please. With the below code

```
 if (con == null || con.isClosed()) con = DBBase.getNewConnection();
    sb = con.createStatement();

    resSet = sb.executeQuery("select * from  USERSAGGRS  where userid='" +user.getUserid()+ "'  AND  id='" +aggid+ "'  ");
```

when load jsp page I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: show the total section of your code please.so as to get an outlook of your program

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the values of `user.getUserid()` and/or `aggid` are the problem. You can test it by printing the query and test that in any Oracle DBMS client.

```
System.out.println("select * from  USERSAGGRS  where userid='" +user.getUserid()+ "'  AND  id='" +aggid+ "'  ")
```

OTOH

The proper way to do is by using [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

```
if (con == null || con.isClosed()) con = DBBase.getNewConnection();
    String SQL = "select * from  USERSAGGRS  where userid=?  AND  id=?"
    sb = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
    sb.setString(1,user.getUserid());
    sb.setString(2,aggid);
    resSet = sb.executeQuery();
```

By using PreparedStatement you can also avoid [SQLInjections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)